# unlink base64 encoded image not working

Tags: php, base64, unlink

hi guys ive created a base64 encoded image captured with web cam now i convert the .png to .jpg all works fine but now i get two images on server both .png and .jpg how do i go about deleting the .png or is their a way to convert to jpg without saving .png image to disk thanx here my code

```
$rawData = $_POST['imgBase64'];
$filteredData = explode(',', $rawData);

$unencoded = base64_decode($filteredData[1]);
$randomName = rand(1000, 99999999999);
//Create the image 
$fp = fopen('user/'.$randomName.'.png', 'w');
fwrite($fp, $unencoded);
//convert image from png to jpg
$image = imagecreatefrompng('user/'.$randomName.'.png');
imagejpeg($image, 'user/'.$randomName.'.jpg', 80);
unlink($fp);
```

ive tried it with

```
unlink($image);

unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/user/.$randomName.'.png'");

imagedestroy($fp);

imagedestroy($image);
```

Comment: In what way does your code not work?

Comment: i dont see why you create the png and not a jpg only

Comment: @APerson code works but i would love to delete .png because it creates both files on server but do not delete .png file after .jpg conversion

Comment: @dagon my image captured from webcam comes in base64 ive read that it only supports .png and will have to convert to .jpg

Comment: use imagecreatefromstring() then imagejpeg()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `unlink()` but passing the file name to it instead of the file handler.

So from your example it would be:

EDIT: You might need to close the file first:

```
fclose( $fp ); 
unlink( 'user/'.$randomName.'.png' );
```

Comment: still not removing the .png my friend

Comment: What about closing the file first?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand all you need is:

```
$data = base64_decode( $_POST['imgBase64']);

// image resource from your  string
$image = imagecreatefromstring($data);

imagejpeg($image, 'user/'.$randomName.'.jpg', 80);
```

Comment: ive given your code a go but now it does not save any image